# upgade from azure 2.4 to 2.5 now diagnostics aren't working

Tags: azure, configuration, visual-studio-2013, azure-diagnostics

I upgraded from azure tools 2.4 to 2.5 and now am getting a null reference thrown when I try to reference the DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration returned by `DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration()` For example

```
DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagnosticConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
diagnosticConfig.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
```

will throw an exception because Directories is null. From what I've googled, the default initial config is stored in the new diagnostics.wadcfgx file, which is there and looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <DiagnosticsConfiguration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
    <PublicConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
<WadCfg>
  <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096">
    <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs />
    <Directories>
      <IISLogs containerName="wad-iis-logfiles" />
    </Directories>
    <PerformanceCounters>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Available MBytes" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\ISAPI Extension Requests/sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\Bytes Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Requests/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Errors Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Queued" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Rejected" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Applications Running" sampleRate="PT0S" />
    </PerformanceCounters>
    <WindowsEventLog scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
      <DataSource name="Application!*" />
    </WindowsEventLog>
    <Logs scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error" />
  </DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
</WadCfg>
<StorageAccount>mystorageaccount</StorageAccount>
</PublicConfig>
<PrivateConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
<StorageAccount name="assetmanagerwms" endpoint="https://core.windows.net/" />
</PrivateConfig>
<IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
</DiagnosticsConfiguration>
```

Does anybody know what I'm missing? All properties are either null or 0 on the returned DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one of the breaking change in SDK 2.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn873976.aspx#BKMK_breaking. Essentially code based diagnostics configuration are no longer supported. From the link above:

> Diagnostics configuration requires diagnostics.wadcfgx; **configuration
>   in code is no longer supported** - With the Azure SDK version 2.5, all
>   diagnostics configuration must be done in the XML configuration file
>   diagnostics.wadcfgx, and the diagnostics agent always uses this
>   configuration, whether it is applied through Visual Studio or Azure
>   PowerShell. **Any previous code-based diagnostics configuration (for
>   example, using the DiagnosticMonitor API) must be migrated to the
>   diagnostics.wadcfgx file**. Code used to configure crash dumps in
>   previous SDKs must also be migrated to the diagnostics.wadcfgx file.
>
> If your Azure SDK version 2.4 project already uses the XML-based
>   diagnostics configuration file diagnostics.wascfg (a recommended best
>   practice), then when you upgrade the project in Visual Studio to
>   target Azure SDK version 2.5, Visual Studio automatically updates the
>   XML configuration file to the new format (diagnostics.wadcfgx). **If
>   your project continues to use a code-based configuration, then when it
>   is upgraded to version 2.5, you will get build warnings that reference
>   the deprecated APIs**. You can use Visual Studio to configure
>   diagnostics.wadcfgx by right-clicking a role in Solution Explorer, and
>   then click Properties. On the Configuration tab, select Enable
>   Diagnostics, and then click Configure. See Configuring Diagnostics for
>   Azure Cloud Services and Virtual Machines for more information.